# C# project in Visual Studio can't find System library after upgrading to Visual Studio 2015 or .NET 4.6.1

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2015

I've got a solution that builds without issue under Windows 8.1 with Visual Studio Professional 2013 (Version 12.0.40629.00 Update 5).  Each project in that environment has a Target framework of ".NET Framework 4.6.1".  I'll call the "Old" environment

When I pull up the solution on a Windows 10 box using Visual Studio Community 2015 (Version 14.0.24720.00 Update 1) a few of the projects under the solution can't locate the "System" assembly.  This is the "New" environment

Properties for System.dll under the "Old" environment in the project that doesn't build under the "New" environment shows an expected path of "C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.6.1\System.dll"

In the same project in the "New" environment the System assembly has no path, Resolved is "False" and has a yellow triangle on the Reference.

I've tried to delete and readd the reference while on the "New" environment, but it still shows the yellow triangle on the reference to the System assembly.

Other projects in the "New" environment have the System assembly resolving with the same path as on the "Old" environment.

I've been picking on the System assembly, but same thing happens in a few projects for any System assembly I reference, like System.Core, System.Data, System.Web, System.Xml, etc...

What am I missing?  What other information do I need to provide to help me get the System assemblies to resolve?

**UPDATE: Figured it why project wasn't building**

In the project file I removed the following and was able to rebuild successfully:

```
<Import Project="$(SolutionDir)\.nuget\NuGet.targets" Condition="Exists('$(SolutionDir)\.nuget\NuGet.targets')" />
  <Target Name="EnsureNuGetPackageBuildImports" BeforeTargets="PrepareForBuild">
    <PropertyGroup>
      <ErrorText>This project references NuGet package(s) that are missing on this computer. Enable NuGet Package Restore to download them.  For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=322105. The missing file is {0}.</ErrorText>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <Error Condition="!Exists('$(SolutionDir)\.nuget\NuGet.targets')" Text="$([System.String]::Format('$(ErrorText)', '$(SolutionDir)\.nuget\NuGet.targets'))" />
  </Target>
```

Why would this Nuget configuration information in the project file stop my project from building, but only on the "New" environment?

Comment: Can you create and build a new one class project on the new machine using VS Community 2015.?  If you can what version of the Framework system.dll is used in that project.

Comment: I was able to create a new project on the new machine using the default framework of 4.5.2 and manually selected framework 4.6.1 for the second.  Both listed the System.dll as Version 4.0.0.0. Framework 4.5.2 has a runtime version of 4.0.30319.  Framework 4.6.1 has a runtime version of same, 4.0.30319.  Both use the path listed in the question above except the version in the path reflects the version selected.